# Is it possible to bind multiple IO Completion ports to a single FilterMngr Port?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-kernel

Currently my program has a single filter port and using the filter manager api functions listens to the request and send the response data to the driver. I want to implement a multithreaded way of retreiving the requests form the filter ports and replying back. IS this possible?

I have tried to attach multiple threads to single IOCP which binds to the filter port and everything works fine, except when the service crashes because theres a heap corruption (double free) somewhere when i am trying to free the memory associated with the response buffer.

I have been looking for a workaround and 1 potential implementation that i cam across was that I can attach multiple IOCP to the filter per thread so that each thread has its own pool of request/reply data. And this way I can ensure that there is no memory intrusion by a foreign party and I am the only one freeing what I have allocated (in this case the response buffer)

Comment: Do you use C or do you use C++? Don't tag both, except your explicitly ask about C vs C++.

Comment: *IOCP which binds to the filter port* - this is how ?